# Odd Django behavior while matching dot in URL

Tags: python, django, django-urls

If I have following url conf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^projects-json$', 'projects.views.list'),
)
```

And I go to `/projects-json` URL resolves fine. Note there is no trailing slash.

But I want to have a dot, not a hyphen in URL, so I rewrite url conf in this way:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^projects\.json$', 'projects.views.list'),
)
```

Now if I go to `/projects.json` I get redirected to `/projects.json/` and get 404 as a consequense! If I add a trailing slash in url pattern I will get OK response at URL with the trailing slash. But I just want one simple thing: to match `/projects.json` without any redirects and slashes. Can Django do this? I've lost so many time for this primitive issue. Could anyone spot a mistake?

`settings.APPEND_SLASH = False`. However looks like it doesn't matter. Just in case it could matter:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
```

Comment: Works fine for me (with `APPEND_SLASH = False`). It can be browser issue, some browsers (Firefox for example) cache redirects, so it will redirect you after there is no redirect at all at server. Try it in another browser. And how do you set `APPEND_SLASH`? In `settings.py`?

Comment: Omg! This is true! The redirect was cached in Firefox. Please, could you post your comment as a reply. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine for me (with `APPEND_SLASH = False`). It can be browser issue, some browsers (Firefox for example) cache redirects, so it will redirect you after there is no redirect at all at server. Try it in another browser.

Comment: I think you can fix this by clearing your cache. I had to do it last week, but forgot specifically what I did...

Comment: Its definitely a cache issue.